# What textbook is this problem from? (circuit analysis)

Tags: circuit-analysis, books

A somewhat unusual question: Some years ago, the following problem appeared in a test I took during my Bachelor's in electrical engineering. Later, the professor told us which textbook he took it from, but for the life of me I can't remember the name. I remember that this book had numerous creative problems, so I'm interested to find it. Can anyone help please? Someone recognizes the style maybe?

[image]

Comment: Using conductance, so it is old school (pre-handheld calculator).

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Perhaps. But I'm looking at the fonts and how they are spaced. Look at \$G_A\$ and how the \$A\$ has a large, but consistent, space gap between it and the \$G\$. If you look at this text here, you will ***also*** see that gap as it is a result of stupid software that doesn't understand kerning well. Compare that with how \$B\$, \$D\$, and \$E\$ (which have straighter backs on the left) are positioned. There was a certain kind of software involved here, which in my opinion ***and*** experience writing such code post-dates handheld calculators.

Comment: I don't recognize it, probably some book that emphasizes network analysis. The 1957 book (1965 printing) "Synthesis of Passive Networks " contains such doozies as [this](https://i.imgur.com/JEwCkUo.png) one, which the author says is the approximate equivalent circuit of a "strapped magnetron".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Wow, glad I never came across a strapped magnetron equivalent circuit on any of my exams!  Not that I could remember that far back anyway :)

Comment: Symbols and labels are non-symmetrical and not aligned well. Looks like regular local-printed workbook, may be from Asian university (they often use american resistor symbol). It can be drawn in usual text editor like MS-word.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit analysis problem is available in the "6.002 Circuits and Electronics" on the MIT Edu website.

Suggested reading for this course is "Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits" by Anant Agarwal and Jeffrey Lang. This circuit problem may not be present in it, however it still has good set of problems.